# How to install hlsdl in windows10

Tags: python, c, encryption, m3u8

I found out a program in GitHub that proclaims to download and decrypt **sample-aes encrypted m3u8**. But it is not clearly mentioned how to install it. **I am newbie in programming and learning python**. But that **program is in c language** so I need some assistance. I installed "haxelib" and installed "hlsdl" by typing "haxelib install hlsdl" in cmd. It downloaded folder named "hlsdl" (in same same directory where I opened cmd) in folder named "lib". **I don't know what to do next** and how to use "hlsdl". Please guide me about what to do next. It would be better if we could discuss it on telegram. **My telegram id: @BishtRajat**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a request for help on another platform, not a concise question for StackExchange.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes get your glasses on. I am asking a question about how to make executable out of a c program. I do not know why am I getting absurd replies instead of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to the Github page:
https://github.com/selsta/hlsdl/blob/master/msvc/BUID_WINDOWS.txt

Comment: I am newbie and I already told in bold letters. Can you please explain? And That is why I gave my telegram id. Although thanks for reply